# IR receivers: how to interpet "Max. Envelope Duty Cycle vs. Burst Length"?

Tags: infrared, datasheet, duty-cycle

In the datasheet of an [IR receiver IC](http://www.vishay.com/docs/82497/tsop753w.pdf), intended for remote control applications, there exists this graph.

Why is there such a sharp translation after a certain carrier impulse count?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datasheet first page:

[image]

So the control circuit (AGC - automatic gain control) circuits suppress background flicker like events to reject unwanted signals.  This effect limits the length of data that can be sent.

This graph from the "Choosing an Infrared Receiver Based on AGC Type" [article](https://www.vishay.com/docs/49860/0811wd_d.pdf) by Vishay shows how the steep cut off filters out flicker sources while attempting to maintain sensitivity to wanted signals.

[image]

Comment: However, this part is recommended for use with the [NEC](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/nec.php) protocol, which contains a 9ms burst as a part of every message. This is 342 impulses, much more than 20. How is this supposed to work out?

Comment: I asked a [separate question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70891/strange-and-contradictory-agc-characteristics-in-datasheet) about this seemingly contradictory behaviour. This makes your answer complete for this question :) Thank you.